# Getting rows sorted by date (only first unique instance on one column) in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table called  "reports" organized as:

```
id | stock_id | type | time_period | report_date
```

type can either be "Cash_Flow", "Income_Statement" or "Balance_Sheet", time_period can either be "quarterly" or "yearly", report_date  is a date. What I'd want to do is essentially get only the most recent (sorted by report_date) reports for each stock_id.

So if  a stock has a "Cash_Flow", "Income_Statement", and "Balance_Sheet" quaterly reports for both 2019-04-30 and 2019-01-30 and yearly reports for 2019-04-30 as well, I'd only want to get the most recent quarterly reports for each stock and not return any yearly reports or any older reports. So let's say there's 100 stocks witih a total of 8 quarters for each report type in the table (2400 rows total for quarterly reports) and 2 yearly reports for each type (600 row yearly reports).

So I'm currently running postgresql 10.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't usually write raw sql (usually use an ORM), so sorry if the answer  is really simple.

So I've tried the following for each report, but it returns all rows(as expected), whereas I'd only want the most recent. I think the solution would likely require a distinct, but I can't get to seem that working with the orderby.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM public.reports where time_period='quarterly' and type='Cash_Flow'  group by id, stock_id order by report_date desc;
```

I'd want a select query that would only return 300 rows, containing only the most recent 3 (Income_Statement, Balance_Sheet, Cash_Flow) reports for each of the 100 stocks or if its easier 3 queries for each of those 3 report  types returning 100 rows each.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd want a select query that would only return 300 rows, containing only the most recent 3 reports for each of the 100 stocks.

Use window functions.  Assuming you have 100 stocks:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stock_id, type order by report_date desc) as seqnum
      from public.reports r
      where time_period = 'quarterly' and
            type in ( 'Cash_Flow', 'Income_Statement', 'Balance_Sheet' )
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry if my question wasn't clear. I meant only the most recent 3  reports as in (Cash_Flow, Balance_Sheet and Income_Statement), or running 3 queries for  each type which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: Getting SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "r"
  Position: 25 for this, is this written for postgresql?

Comment: @smw . . . That is actually just a slight tweak to the query (and it makes more sense).  As for phrasing, you should say that you want the most recent report of each type, not the three most recent reports.